# GraphQL matrix schema different types

Tags: graphql, graphql-schema

I want to retrieve a matrix from GraphQL server with this structure:

```
[
 ['Country', 'Popularity'],
 ['Germany', 200],
 ['United States', 300],
 ['Brazil', 400],
 ['Canada', 500],
 ['France', 600],
 ['RU', 700]
]
```

My actual schema is like this

```
type MyType{
  data: [[String]]
}
```

And this actually works but the problem is that I want this data for a [Google GeoChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart) and the expected pair values are for the first one String-String (`['Country', 'Popularity']`) and next ones String-Number (`[Germany', 200]`).

This example has 7 lists but the server can return a different number of lists, it can be a different value for each request.

Calling my endpoint with schema `[[String]]` all values are sending correctly but numbers are parsed to String and I have to iterate in the frontend to parse every value to a Number.

Is there a way to define the schema something like `[[Any]]` and values are not parsed to String?

Thanks.

Comment: https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#union-types

Comment: Hi @xadm thanks for the link. Can you explain me how can I use union types to get the desired schema? Thanks

Comment: just try to define some `StringOrNumber` and use instead of original `String` ?

Comment: Can you add an answer with a better explanation please @xadm?